# R Leaflet: Plot non-overlapping parallel lines

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I need to plot two parallel lines between some cities in Leaflet. I know how to plot lines using addPolyLines(), but how can I produce parallel lines, which should almost touch each other, but not overlap? Is there some way of knowing how much space the line currently takes on the map?

Comment: the line width is in pixels